# Dog fatally attacks burglar. Is owner guily of anything?

Tags: united-kingdom, liability, death, dog

A person owns a large, potentially
dangerous dog breed such as the XL Bully, which was recently restricted in the UK. It is owned legally; the dog is registered, neutered, and all safety requirements are followed. During the night, this home is burgled and the dog, out of fear, attacks and kills this intruder. The owner, being in bed, had no time to get downstairs and intervene. The dog attacked out of fear, and I'm assuming there are no requirements for a dog to he muzzled or confined withing their own home so the owner, as far as I'm aware, has done nothing wrong. Would would the owner be guilty of anything criminally, or be liable for wrongful death suit?

Comment: Is there a "beware of dog" sign?

Comment: @phoog - regarding inside their house, probably not. The owner would likely just verbally warn anyone was permitted to enter their property.

Answer (score 1):

Louisiana, USA Civil Code (Louisiana is more likely to place civil liability codes in statutes versus common  law, though common law does apply in LA).

> Art. 2321.  Damage caused by animals
>
> The owner of an animal is answerable for the damage caused by the
> animal.  However, he is answerable for the damage only upon a showing
> that he knew or, in the exercise of reasonable care, should have known
> that his animal's behavior would cause damage, that the damage could
> have been prevented by the exercise of reasonable care, and that he
> failed to exercise such reasonable care.  Nonetheless, the owner of a
> dog is strictly liable for damages for injuries to persons or property
> caused by the dog and which the owner could have prevented and **which
> did not result from the injured person's provocation of the dog**
> [emphasis mine].  Nothing in this Article shall preclude the court
> from the application of the doctrine of res ipsa loquitur in an
> appropriate case.

A burglar's presence would likely be assumed to provoke a dog, but from a civil standpoint this would be adjudicated at trial.  I find it unlikely a burglar's estate would prevail.  Notwithstanding urban legends of crooks suing from getting injured while committing robbery, this is just not permitted any more without extreme extenuating circumstances.

Criminality of defense against a burglar would fall under Castle Doctrine.  Castle doctrine in Louisiana a permits use of deadly force against an intruder.  This does not implicitly give your dog permission to kill an intruder, but I find any outcome other than declaring the dog a hero  unlikely.

> Louisiana Revied Statute 14:20
>
> §20.  Justifiable homicide
>
> A.  A homicide is justifiable... (4)(a)  When committed by a person
> lawfully inside a dwelling, a place of business, or a motor vehicle as
> defined in R.S. 32:1(40) when the conflict began, against a person who
> is attempting to make an unlawful entry into the dwelling, place of
> business, or motor vehicle, or who has made an unlawful entry into the
> dwelling, place of business, or motor vehicle, and the person
> committing the homicide reasonably believes that the use of deadly
> force is necessary to prevent the entry or to compel the intruder to
> leave the dwelling, place of business, or motor vehicle.

Comment: The justifiable homicide statute is certainly helpful for context, but it's not directly relevant since there's no homicide here.

Comment: @phoog, dog owners have been charged criminally due to dog attacks

Comment: I don't doubt it, but I do doubt that they've been charged with homicide under the quoted statute.